# Unable to set raster surface resolution in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, landsat, resolution, drape

I have a 3-band subset of a Landsat image which I want to display in ArcScene (of ArcGIS version 10.2.1).

The image is 30 meter resolution and I am draping it on a 25m resolution Aster DEM. But have problems with the resolution.

Whether I set the cell size to 25m, 30m, 1m or 1000m, the result is always 6o meter pixels! Rendering the image in a high quality does not help.

Did anyone experience this and is able to help?

---

I do exacty that - but don't get the expected result.

Setting the surface resolution:
[image]

Rendering at the highest quality:
[image]

Result: 
[image]

[image]

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Exactly where are you setting the raster resolution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Base Surface cell size Raster Surface Resolution. This is in the Image (not the dem) layer properties:  Base Height Tab -> Raster Resolution button (in the Elevation from Surfaces section) -> change cellsize X and Y to 30m.

Also note the Original surface cell-size. You cannot enter a number lower than the Original surface. If your raster files are very large, lowering this number will cause ArcScene to re-render the scene and it may take a considerable amount of time.  Once rendered, it will be responsive but when you close the ArcScence document and re-open it will re-render again.  This is an issue for me when I render high resolution aerial imagery draped over  Lidar surface for example and I change[image] the Cellsize X, Y to the full resolution of the LiDAR.